# Is there a workaround to get WFS 'FeatureTypes' in a list with Python? I get timeout issues etc. with OWSLib

Tags: python, pyqgis, wfs, owslib

I have successfully been able to get the Feature type list from below answer, but only for smaller WFS datasets.

[Importing all layers available on server for WFS in PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234277/importing-all-layers-available-on-server-for-wfs-in-pyqgis)

I need a workaround to get feature type list from larger WFS datasets due to eg. timeouts and loading time. 
My current code is:

```
    from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService
    wfs = WebFeatureService(url='https://.........../geoserver/ows?', version='1.0.0')
    list(wfs.contents)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There are no workarounds for getting a list of featuretypes from a WFS server. The application must send a GetCapabilities request and parse it. The request is like this https://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetCapabilities. owslib must use that request as well on the background. If server hits timeout for GetCapabilities it is useless. Contact the server admins if that happens. But I do not know owslib and it may do also some other requests like DescribeFeatureType that you do not need for gettting a list or featuretypes.

Comment: @ user30184 you don't need a GetCapabilities request to get the list of all featuretypes from a WFS server you could just use a describefeaturetype and specify no typename.  That said, the approach is likely to be just as slow